# Android Application process scope in memory

Tags: android, process

Dear Folks,
             I have idea regarding the general Memory Structure and how the OS manages the memory by using different mechanism! 
             I know that android uses linux kernel and there would be memory management module which would control access the way the memory is allocated to a process.

I recently had my doubt arising when i ran through the Out of memory exception in android. 
             Consider I have 10 images to be displayed in an activity and when my application opens the said activity all the 10 images would be loaded in memory and will be in the primary memory until my app is pushed to the background. This is how I understood so far regarding the processes in any operation system.

But I also ran into the doubt once the images are loaded in the memory and dispatched to the GUI I mean set to the activity , will not those images be present in primary memory or they will be cleared out from the memory ?

Please help me in understanding this!

I already Google -ed it, but not able to find what I needed

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely wrong. You should not load 10 full sized images at all. You usually load them way smaller, directly from the disk into Thumbnails that are not a few megabytes each. You should read this article: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: I will not load full sized images I will convert them to smaller once and will load . But My question is, will those images resides in the memory after they are shown up in the view of the activity or they will not ?

Comment: Yes they will as the system has to hold on to the image data.